# What is the performance impact of having a subscription on multiple RxJS observables during a whole session of my Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, rxjs, ngrx

I'm working on an Angular app where we want to track some action events in order make some reporting.

One of the objectives is to keep the components logic as clean as possible and **reduce the tracking performance impact** as mush as possible.

One way we may choose to implement this inspired from ngrx effects is to declare specific tracker observables (with RxJS, one per action event), **merge them and subscribe to the merged observable at app startup** (keeping it alive during the whole session). Each tracker filtering on a specific action event.
This way allows us to dispatch action events on a subject in our components which are handled by the trackers asynchronously aside from the flow of the app.

Today we have around 30 events (so 30 observables to merge) but maybe one day there will be hundreds (hundreds of observables to merge).

**What is the impact in terms of performance of having those RxJS observables ?

Does merging them and having only one subscription reduce the impact ?**

---

EDIT 1: A practice test showed that the merging and the single subscription makes no notable difference

Comment: What is your specific performance requirement, and how far away are you from that right now?

Comment: I'd use nodejs profiler and measure performance with 10 vs 100 observables

Comment: Right now there's no official requirement, we're just thinking of checking the Memory footprint/CPU in the browser Task Manager. The unofficial requirement would be that those measurements are not notably impacted by the observables.
A test with Chrome task manager showed that 100 running observables executing an empty function every second (kind of similar to the filter function we would have) permanently raises the CPU measurement to ~9 from 0

Comment: The sad reality is that the NgRx team is way better than I am because with 100 effects the CPU raises to 0.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no difference if you use merge to subscribe to all of them or subscribe to every single one on it's own. The only difference here is that you share common behavior, like error and complete signals.